# How much time need for finish the work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two employees can perform a job for $\frac{20}3$ hours. How much time is needed to see his worker to perform work , if for him needs $3$ hours less than the second worker would own work.

My attempt is: $$\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{1}{y}=1$$
and
$$x+y=\frac{20}{3}$$

I didn't now it is correct. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think about the rates of work, which is defined as
$$\text{rate of work}=\frac{\text{number of jobs}}{\text{time taken}}$$

Let's say the unknown, the time in hours the worker needs to do one job, is $t$. Then his rate of work is $\frac 1t$. The second worker needs $t+3$ hours to do the job, so his rate of work is $\frac 1{t+3}$.

The two employees do one job in $\frac{20}3$ hours, so their combined rate is $\dfrac 1{\frac{20}3}=\frac 3{20}$. We can also add their individual rates to get their combined rates. We therefore end up with the equation

$$\frac 1t+\frac 1{t+3}=\frac 3{20}$$

Just solve that equation for $t$ and you have your answer. You will get a quadratic equation in $t$, so I hope you can solve quadratic equations. You will get two possible values for $t$, one positive and one negative. Your desired answer will be the positive value.